# WooCommerce product attributes hitting max_input_vars limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Building a WooCommerce shop for a client which involves highly customisable products. These customisations are specified using the WooCommerce product attributes.

Because of the way this function works in WooCommerce, publishing a product results in exceeding the max_input_vars limit of 1000 in PHP.

I am aware that there are (paid for) plugins for WooCommerce which supposedly get around this problem, but before overloading this site with yet another plugin I wanted to explore increasing the max_input_vars value in php.ini.

I would have to increase the max_input_vars limit to (at an initial estimate) 6000. I would limit this change to apply to the wp-admin directory of this particular Wordpress site only. It's on a VPS we have sole use of (although we host other websites on it).

My question is: What likely performance or security issues for the site / server would arise from settings max_input_vars to 6000?

Comment: As an alternative you might want to try [WooCommerce Ninja Forms Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-ninjaforms-product-addons/) or [WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/).Either would allow you to set very customizable products via forms. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the effects of modifying `max_input_vars`.

Comment: Yes, I have seen several plug-ins, both free and paid-for that offer a supposed solution, however the site is already bloated with almost two dozen plug-ins (against my advice) and I didn't want to be responsible for adding another. I wanted to explore this as an option before resorting to that.

Comment: Adding a plugin isn't evil if it does what you need. Because I don't know about `max_input_vars` I'd probably opt for the plugin for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just gone ahead and done it, I have found that while the site is a little slow in adding products with a large number of variations, it has not had any impact of the server's performance.

I can say that I am not entirely content with the way WooCommerce manages variations.